# Time cannot run brunch?

Tags: android, linux, bash, sh

I'm having an issue with the `time` command.
I use `/usr/bin/time` so i can use the `-f` and `-o` modifiers.

My script is:

```
make clean
repo sync -j5
. ./platform_manifest/manual_add_kernel_manifest.sh \
  && . build/envsetup.sh \
  && /usr/bin/time -o log$day$month.log -f "Buildtime: %E" brunch aokp_mako-eng
```

The script is part of an automated build system for an android ROM.

When it gets to the time part, i get:

```
/usr/bin/time: cannot run brunch: No such file or directory
Command exited with non-zero status 127
Buildtime: 0:00.00
```

Brunch works fine with the regular `time` command, but I cannot route its output to a file, which is why I am using `/usr/bin/time` in the first place. If there is a way to do this, that is fine for me as I can trim off the `real:` header with `| awk '{ print $2 }'`.

Any help is appreciated!

Ubuntu 12.04, all updates installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what `brunch` is, but the most likely reason that a *non*-builtin `time` program can't find it, even when the built-in `time` *can*, is that it's a shell function or a Bash alias.

Whether or not that's the case . . .

> […] I cannot route [the regular `time` command's] output to a file […]

You can write:

```
{ time brunch aokp_mako-eng ; } 2>"log$day$month.log"
```

to wrap `time` (and everything else) into a command-list whose STDERR has already been redirected to the file.